# a problem for plotting a vertical line on chart js using jinja template array

Tags: flask, chart.js, jinja2

I have a small issue but it's somehow confusing. I am trying to draw a 2 y-axes chart on my web app using Flask, Jinja and Chart.JS as plotting library.

It worked well but when I try to plot a vertical line on the chart, it only works with an array, i.e.: `data: [1, 2, 3, 4]`. When I pass the template, it doesn't plot the vertical line – only the chart data is visible, but the line disappears. How do I fix this?

Here is the code:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('chart_{{prop.name}}').getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'bar', // <-- define overall chart type
    data: {
        labels: [
            {% for item in prop.histoDataPoints %}
                "{{item}}",
            {% endfor %}
        ],
        datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            label: 'Density',
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,102,102,255)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [
                {% for item in prop.density %} 
                    {{ item }},
                {% endfor %}
            ],
            yAxisID: 'left-axis'

        }, {
            label: 'Distribution',
            fill: true,

            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,102,102,255)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [
                {% for item in prop.distribution %}
                    {{ item }},
                {% endfor %}
            ],
            yAxisID: 'right-axis'
        }]
    },
    options: {

        scales: {

            yAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                id: 'left-axis',
                display: true,
                position: 'left',
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: '%'
                }
            }, {
                type: 'linear',
                id: 'right-axis',
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
                stacked: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: '#'
                },
                gridLines: {
                    drawOnChartArea: true
                }
            }]

        },
        annotation: {
            annotations: [{
                type: 'line',
                mode: 'vertical',
                scaleID: "x-axis-0",
                value: 573.5,
                borderColor: 'rgb(75, 0, 0)',
                borderWidth: 4,
                label: {
                    enabled: true,
                    content: 'Test label'
                }
            }]
        }

    }
});
```